# Display doesn't go into standby

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend, display

Recently reloaded my system with Xubuntu 18.04.03 because my hard drive was on it's last leg.

I can't seem to get the Dell display to go into standby mode. It seems to be related to the Nvidia driver (I have a GT 710). The version of driver also seems to affect being able to wake the system up with keyboard/mouse activity(with some versions of the driver, I can't wake the system up, but with others I can).

I'm currently on driver version 440.26 and the screen blanks but doesnt go into sleep. I see it flicker for a split second (maybe it tries to go into standby?) but then I can see that the display is still on.

If I enter this command, it only blanks the screen - the display doesnt go into standby like it did with my old setup.

```
sleep 1; xset dpms force standby
```

Also, this doesn't turn off the display either - it just blanks the screen.

```
sleep 1; xset dpms force off
```

Any tricks to get a current system with an Nvidia card to properly handle standby on a display?

Answer (score 0):

I have a hack that I use to make certain that my machine locks just in case, because I have had one instance in which VLC Media Player prevented my desktop from locking, which led to someone getting unauthorized access. If you are on Ubuntu > 18 then you should be on Gnome, in which case if you run this as a cron job, it should lock your machine:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Auto Lock Gnome Session
# Run as cron - example - lock every 5 minutes:
# cat <<< '
# 5 * * * * * /usr/local/bin/autolock ' |crontab -

gnome-screensaver-command --lock
```

Not sure about the drivers, but this "trick" may help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Chev! My system seems to lock fine, it just doesn't handle the power saver features of the monitor correctly. I'd rather the monitor go into standby, so my hunt for an answer continues...

Comment: OK, this seems to work.
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --off; read -n1; xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --auto
It goes blank, then into power saver mode, then wakes back up when I press a key. So at least I know my system can put the monitor to sleep with an Nvidia driver.
How can I find out what the system is using to put the monitor to sleep? Maybe I can just substitute in this xrandr command to put it to sleep and wake it up.

Comment: My display works now, but I'm not using Xubuntu so I'm not sure what fixed it, the driver (418.74) or the kernel (4.19.0-6-AMD64) or something else.